# MySQL Database Indexing Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

I have a database that I am trying to index

The index I have created is as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX <name> ON geoplanet_places(name(15));
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM geoplanet_places WHERE name LIKE "vancouver%";
```

The result is returned in less than 1 seconds

When I run this query (note the aditional '%' wild card):

```
SELECT * FROM geoplanet_places WHERE name LIKE "%vancouver%";
```

The result return time is greatly increased, sometimes clocking in at over 9 seconds. This is about the same amount of time it took before the database was indexed.

The database has over 5 million records, I understand why it is slowing down. What i'd like to know is if there is anyway to do the wild card before the name without taken such a huge performance hit in MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL indexes are created from the leading part of the column - the first query looks for 'vancouver' at the start of the column - entirely within the 15 chars of the index.  However the second query looks for 'vancouver' *anywhere* within the column - there's no guarantee that it will be within the 15 char of the index (and I'd be very surprised if the index would be able to look somewhere other than the start of the indexed string section) - if you looked at the query plan you would probably see a tablescan where the engine is looking at all values in the column sequentially.

It looks a little as though you should investigate MySQL's [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index - last time I looked at it it was not good enough to make a search engine, but it might solve your problem (it also looks as if modern MySQL supports FULLTEXT indexes on InnoDB tables as well as the MyISAM tables it was historically restricted to).